# How to load Enumeration Values to Combobox in TableView Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to add an enumeration value to a Combobox to a TableView (Javafx).
I tried multiple codes online however the only one that worked stopped working when tried to added an Edit event due to string to Enum conversion problem.
this is my code :

```
    this.tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("etat"));
    this.tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Utilisateur, Utilisateur.Etat>forTableColumn());
    tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Utilisateur, Utilisateur.Etat> t) -> {

                if (t.getNewValue().equals("actif")) {
                    ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(User.Etat.Actif);
                } else {
                    ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(User.Etat.Bloque);

                }

            });
```

where tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat is the Column where I want to put the Value of Etat :

```
    private TableColumn<Utilisateur, Utilisateur.Etat> tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat;
```

Utilisateur.Etat :

```
    public enum Etat {
      Actif,Bloque}
```

PS : this code is for TextField and not Combobox, even this doesn't work anymore.
this is a screenshot for the error that came out : 
[image]

PS : I modified my code like this :

```
    this.tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("etat"));
    Utilisateur User = new Utilisateur();
    this.tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<Utilisateur,Utilisateur.Etat>forTableColumn(User.getEtat()));
    tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setOnEditCommit(
            (CellEditEvent<Utilisateur, Utilisateur.Etat> t) -> {

                if (t.getNewValue().equals(User.Etat.Actif)) {
                    ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(User.Etat.Actif);
                } else {
                    ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(User.Etat.Bloque);

                }

            });
```

now I get this : 
[image]

my problem is : how to load the two values of Utilisateur.Etat in a Combobox in Tableview, with the Edit Event ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works :

```
     Etat etat = Etat.Actif ;

    this.tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.<Utilisateur,Etat>forTableColumn(etat.values()));
    tv_ListUsers_cl_Etat.setOnEditCommit(
        (CellEditEvent<Utilisateur, Etat> t) -> {

            if (t.getNewValue().equals(Etat.Actif)) {
                ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(Etat.Actif);
            } else {
                ((Utilisateur) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setEtat(Etat.Bloque);

            }

        });
```

I added Etat.java containing this :

```
    public enum Etat {

Actif,Bloque
     }
```